# PHP session is restarting instead of resuming

Tags: php, session, unity-game-engine

I am unity3d to make a login/logout screen for my game. I am assigning values to the session variable during login. It is working fine in the browser but if i call the logout from unity it always says "user not logged in".

It means the session variable is going back to NULL or the session is restarting inside the logout.php instead of resuming. How do i solve this?

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

 $servername="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="xxxx";
 $database="database";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // =============================================================================
    $unityHash = $_POST["unity_hash"];
    $phpHash = "hashcode"; // same code in here as in your Unity game

    $player = $_POST["form_name"]; //I use that function to protect against SQL injection
    $password = $_POST["form_password"];

    if(!$player || !$password) {
        echo "Login or password cant be empty.";
    } else {
        if ($unityHash != $phpHash){
            echo "HASH code is diferent from your game, you infidel.";
        } else {
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM players WHERE player = '$player' LIMIT 1");
            $sql->execute();            
            if($sql->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
                        echo "successfully logged in";
                        //update the state
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE players SET state='1' WHERE player= '$player' AND password = '$row[password]'");
                        $stmt->execute();   
//SESSION VARIABLE ASSIGNMENT  
                            $_SESSION["form_name"] = $player;
                            $_SESSION["form_password"] = $row['password'];

                        }
                        else{
                        echo "Wrong password";
                        }

                }
                else{
                    echo "Data invalid - cant find name.";
                }               
            }
        }
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    $conn = null;
    ?>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["form_password"];

if(isset($_SESSION["form_name"])){
    unset($_SESSION["form_name"]);
    unset($_SESSION["form_password"]);
    echo "successfully logged out"; 
}

else{
echo "user not logged in"; 
}        
?>
```

I am getting the following error if i try to print $_SESSION["form_password"]

`<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: form_password in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aditya\logout.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />`

Code inside unity

```
IEnumerator LoginUser(){
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("form_name" , form_name);
        form.AddField("form_password" , form_password );
        form.AddField("unity_hash" , unity_hash);

        WWW login = new WWW(login_url, form);

        yield return login;

        // check for errors
        if (login.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log(login.text);

        } else {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ login.error);
        } 
    }

    IEnumerator LogoutUser(){

        WWW logout = new WWW(logout_url);

        yield return logout;

        // check for errors
        if (logout.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log(logout.text);

        } else {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ logout.error);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about Unity3D but the most obvious answer would be that your Unity script is not capable of saving/handling cookies.

Comment: Is there any other way to implement logout?

Comment: Save PHP's session ID in your Unity script on log in and on log out pass it as a GET parameter to the server. You can then use that parameter to retrieve the session. See [session_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php).

Comment: k, its working. i am using `echo session_id()`. Storing it in unity and sending it back to logout.php using the WWWform like i did in my login method above. Is there any advantage in using the GET parameter  instead of this?